# what is the Permission denied? how to solve this warning error?

Tags: php, mysql

```
Warning: fopen(/home/a/public_html/debug/php_error_log.txt) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/a/public_html/includes/functions/general.php on line 33

Warning: flock() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/a/public_html/includes/functions/general.php on line 34

Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/a/public_html/includes/functions/general.php on line 35

Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/a/public_html/includes/functions/general.php on line 36

Warning: flock() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/a/public_html/includes/functions/general.php on line 37

Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/a/public_html/includes/functions/general.php on line 38
Unable to connect to database server!
```

Comment: Perhaps you could provide the code causing this error?

Answer (score 2):

Your PHP script cannot access the file `/home/a/public_html/debug/php_error_log.txt`

Try to `cat` it, you should get a permission denied as well.

To fix the problem, you should change the rights of the file with `chmod` or change the ownership with `chown`